# Vim: restart search from beginning of file?

Tags: vim

If I get to the last occurrence of a search term in vim and use `/` to find the next instance, it says "Pattern not found". How do I restart the search from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enable the `'wrapscan'` option:

```
:set wrapscan
```

Description of the option from `:h 'ws`:

```
'wrapscan' 'ws'     boolean (default on)            *E384* *E385*
            global
    Searches wrap around the end of the file.  Also applies to |]s| and
    |[s|, searching for spelling mistakes.
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I wasn't paying attention and was actually using `less` instead of `vim` – `vim` does in fact wrap by default. If anyone does run into this problem, though, this is in fact the right answer.